# Aggregate with subselect or subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to make a query that returns how much I can produce based on the lowest value of a sum of component units from different warehouses.

Data come from tables like these:

```
e.table
-------
codartp    codartc      unicompo
REF1       BLISTER1       1
REF1       BOX1           1
REF1       CHARGER1       2
REF2       BLISTER2       1
REF2       BOX2           1

s.table
------
codart      unidades      codalm
BLISTER1      100           4 
BLISTER1      150           1
BOX1          100           1
BOX1          100           4
BOX1          200           2
CHARGER1      50            3
CHARGER1      50            4 
BLISTER2      500           1
BLISTER2      300           4 
BOX2          150           2
```

I would need to sum how much I have from every component (blister, box, charger...) in total:
BLISTER1: 250
BOX1: 400
CHARGER1: 100

And then return the lowest value divided by the unicompo (the number of components I need). With my stock of components, I could only produce 50 units of REF1: 100/2

Here is my subselect:

```
(select min(val) from (select sum(s1.unidades/e.unicompo) as val 
    from __STOCKALMART s1
    left join escandallo e on e.codartc = s1.codart
    where s1.codalm not in (0,9999) and e.codartp = l.codart) t) as PRODUCIBLE
```

The expected result would be something like this:

```
l.codart  producible
REF1          50
REF2          150
```

But I only managed to call either the min (in some warehouses is 0) or the sum of components, not min after the sum. I don't know if I'm explaining myself. Ask if I need to clarify anything

Thanks for your help

Comment: please show the expected result and the complete query

Comment: @Squirrel sorry, I just did

Comment: The **complete** query, not just the subquery. You probably need to `APPLY` the subquery so you can get multiple rows and columns

Comment: @Charlieface the complete query would be
`select l.codart, (subquery)
from linepedi
and lots of filters`
I think the problem is on the subquery... =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is no overlap between your product compositions (so no two products share a common component, otherwise you are looking at something way more complex), then the query below should give you a solution.

**Sample data**

```
create table ProductComponent
(
  codartp nvarchar(4),  -- product
  codartc nvarchar(10), -- component
  unicompo int          -- amount
);

insert into ProductComponent (codartp, codartc, unicompo) values
('REF1', 'BLISTER1', 1),
('REF1', 'BOX1'    , 1),
('REF1', 'CHARGER1', 2),
('REF2', 'BLISTER2', 1),
('REF2', 'BOX2'    , 1);

create table ComponentInventory
(
  codart nvarchar(10), -- component
  unidades int,        -- amount
  codalm int           -- warehouse
);

insert into ComponentInventory (codart, unidades, codalm) values
('BLISTER1', 100, 4), 
('BLISTER1', 150, 1),
('BOX1'    , 100, 1),
('BOX1'    , 100, 4),
('BOX1'    , 200, 2),
('CHARGER1', 50 , 3),
('CHARGER1', 50 , 4), 
('BLISTER2', 500, 1),
('BLISTER2', 300, 4), 
('BOX2'    , 150, 2);
```

**Solution**

Using some common table expressions (CTE's) to:

1. Sum up all the inventory components across the warehouses.
2. Divide the previous sums according to the product composition.

This gives:

```
with cti as -- component inventory total
(
  select ci.codart,
         sum(ci.unidades) as unidades
  from ComponentInventory ci
  group by ci.codart
),
pci as -- product component inventory
(
  select pc.codartp,
         cti.unidades / pc.unicompo as maxPart
  from ProductComponent pc
  join cti
    on cti.codart = pc.codartc
)
select pci.codartp,
       min(pci.maxPart) as producibleAmount
from pci
group by pci.codartp
order by pci.codartp;
```

**Result**

```
codartp producibleAmount
------- ----------------
REF1    50
REF2    150
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=226a54834724f5b68eec0f3de8adfbc3) to see it in action with intermediate CTE results.

Comment: Sometimes a component is shared by two products, but I want to return how many I can produce without taking that in mind (if I waste my components producing 'A', won't be able to produce 'B', but I want to know I can produce them). In the other hand, is there any way to achieve that without having to create so much tables? I have thousands of components and products and I would like to use the tables from system. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, Ok, sorry, I just saw it works with my base tables. Thank you very much